LucidChart - how to group tabs/pages into folders?
I frequently use LucidChart to document/diagram APIs.  Diagrams of complex APIs often require multiple tabs or pages to capture all the details at various levels of abstraction, resulting in a long line of tabs at the bottom of the diagram (many of which don't fit on the screen, requiring the use of the navigation errors to see).
This, of course, makes for an unintiutive experience for someone wishing to view the diagram.
The obvious fix would be to group the tabs/pages into folders (similar to the Chrome browser's "Tab Groups" functionality).
Is there a way to do this in LucidChart?
